# Exists: power to outlet1 to outlet2 to switch - can't change wiring, would like switch to control only outlet #2

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, receptacle

Not sure how I would make the connections at outlet #2 and switch to control outlet #2??

Any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I would add some images of what outlet #2 looks like, as well as your switch. Your diagram is too generic to answer this at present.

Comment: There are problems if your drawing intends to represents what exists, with the number of wires shown receptacle #1 cannot be currently switched, the black can't be switched and hot. Then your white between receptacle #2 must be connected to the hot side. Maybe some pictures of the receptacles pulled from the wall would be better.

Comment: Do you want both sockets on outlet #2 to be switched on only one?

Answer (score 2):

- Connect the white wire between outlet #1 to #2 to the neutral screw on outlet #2. (Do not break the tab on the neutral side.)
- Break the tab on the hot side of outlet #2.
- Use a wirenut and a short piece of black wire to connect the two black wires for outlet #2 to one hot screw on outlet #2. This will be your unswitched outlet.
- Connect the white wire to the other hot screw. This will be your switched outlet. Wrap some electrical tape around the ends of the white wire from the switch. This is an indicator to future people that the wire is a switched hot, and not a neutral.

[image]

**Note:**

- If this is new construction or a permitted remodel where you have removed the drywall (and you therefore have to meet the newer electrical code),
- Or you want to install a smart switch that requires a neutral wire...

...then you will have to replace the cable between outlet #2 and the switch with some /3 cable. In that case, you would use the red wire between the switch and the outlet, and instead connect the white wire to the neutral side of outlet #2, and leave the white wire unconnected in the switch box (or connected to you smart switch).

Comment: Well done, graphic and all!  Except the marked white wire needs to be the always-hot because of a Code requirement that seems superfluous if the wire is actually marked.

Comment: Thank you longneck! I'll be testing it out later today...

Comment: NEC 404.3(C)(5) permits not extending a neutral to switches controlling receptacle lighting loads.